# cabal install does not upgrade cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I have upgraded cabal install (using a capital C for `Cabal`)

```
$cabal install Cabal cabal-install

[...]

Configuring cabal-install-1.24.0.2...
Building cabal-install-1.24.0.2...
Installed cabal-install-1.24.0.2
```

after a lengthy output in terminal, then I check that cabal has been updated, it hasn't changed

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

I am looking for where the new installation of cabal might be

```
$ which cabal
/usr/local/bin/cabal

$ /usr/local/bin/cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```

Not entirely sure what I have found.

Comment: [TFM](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install): *By default the cabal tool will install programs in ~/.cabal/bin/*

Comment: @n.m. now it says `$ ~/.cabal/bin/cabal new-build reflex`  then it says `BadPackageLocations [BadLocGlobEmptyMatch "./*.cabal"]`