# cabal 1.24 says BadPackageLocations

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

After upgrading to Cabal 1.24 I can't install new programs

```
$ cabal new-build reflex
BadPackageLocations [BadLocGlobEmptyMatch "./*.cabal"]
```

See my other question: [cabal install does not upgrade cabal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321540/cabal-install-does-not-upgrade-cabal)

Comment: That error sure could use some work! That said: I'm guessing you aren't in a cabal project directory. `cabal new-build` and friends work a bit differently from `cabal install`; you can't just `new-build` a given package. You can list it as a package to be included in a given project, though.

Comment: (Digression: @DanielWagner "you can't just `new-build` a given package. You can list it as a package to be included in a given project, though" -- That is, it is roughly like `stack build` is typically used to install dependencies?)

Comment: @duplode I'm not familiar enough with stack to say for sure, but that sounds roughly right: `new-build` will install all of the dependencies of the specified build targets automatically.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have no idea what a cabal project directory is.  I am trying to install reflex and someone suggested I use `new-build`, but I have no idea to use it correctly

Comment: @johnmangual Just start writing the package you want to make with reflex, and have it depend on reflex. When you `cabal new-build` your package the first time, it will make install reflex. For more concrete instructions: run `cabal init` in a new directory, add `reflex` to the dependencies in the `*.cabal` file that generates, then run `cabal new-build`.